# Как работает такой пример с рекурсией?

Tags: javascript, функции, рекурсия

Есть такой пример кода, мне не совсем понятно что конкретно в нем происходит. Как я понимаю...:

1. Сначала происходит вызов ф-ции `pow()` - функция запускается. На первом запуске этой ф-ции `n` равно 3.
2. Выполнение кода на первом запуске доходит до `else` - происходит второй вызов ф-ции `pow()`. Здесь `n` равно 2.
3. Выполнение кода снова доходит до `else` - происходит третий запуск ф-ции `pow()`. На третьем запуске n равно 1 - срабатывает `if`, происходит `return x`, дальше происходит выход этой ф-ции из стека вызовов.
4. Потом происходит возврат ко 2-му вызову, где ф-ция продолжает выполняться с того места, где ее выполнение приостановилось. То есть по сути это строка `return x * pow(x, n - 1)`...

И вот здесь мне становится непонятно, как `x` может умножаться на `x`, если рекурсивный вызов ф-ции `pow()` в этой строке ничего не возвращает? Ну то есть мне непонятно как по сути это выражение может выдавать какое-то значение, если `pow` не возвращает какое-то значение. На что умножается `x`
?

```js
function pow(x, n) {
    if (n == 1) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return x * pow(x, n - 1);
    }
  }
  
console.log( pow(2, 3) ); //8
```

Comment: Почему ты решил что ничего не возвращает, если в функции есть аж два места с `return` ?

Comment: "ничего не возвращает" - не понял, `return x` замечательно всё возвращает